# How to display live count of number of characters left in EditText in xamarin android

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, .net-framework-version

my question about How to display live count of number of characters left in EditText in xamarin android using Mvvm Cross

Comment: We're probably not going to be able to help unless you edit your question to include what you've tried with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, your question is very generic, so should my answer be, I am giving you everything to get the count when you change the edit text binded to a property, rest you should do.

You would create a property in your viewmodel.

Something like

```
Public String ContactName { 
get 
{
return ContactName;
} 
set {
ContactName = value; 
RaisePropertyChange (() => ContactName);
}
}
```

This property you would bind to your editTest outlet, that might look something like.

```
var set = This.CreateBindingSet<MyView,MyViewModel>();
set.Bind(YourEditText).To(Vm => vm. ContactName). WithConversion("MyConverter");
set.Apply();
```

Now you need to write a converter that would return you int from string.

Something like this.

```
 public class MyConverter: MvxValueConverter<string, int> 
{
    protected override Int Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return   value.Length;
    }

}
```

And this would give you exactly want you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
     // xaml page 

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Label Text="Document Description:" FontSize="20"  
    TextColor="Black"/>
            <Frame CornerRadius="5"  Padding="20">
                <StackLayout>
                    <controls:BorderlessEditor  AutoSize="TextChanges" 
 Placeholder="Enter Description" x:Name="CharacterEntry" 
 TextChanged="CharacterEntry_TextChanged" MaxLength="500"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Label x:Name="CharacterCount" TextColor="Red"/>
        </StackLayout> 
        
        
        
    // xaml.cs page     
    
    
    private void CharacterEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int maxcount = 500;
        CharacterCount.Text = Convert.ToString(maxcount - CharacterEntry.Text.Length) + " characters are left ";
    }
```